# How can I implement sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: and tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex: methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am using Realm v0.98.1 and `RBQFetchedResultsController`.

Basically, I want a tableview list with section header names as first letter & section index titles along with search functionality.

The problem is `RBQFetchedResultsController` differs from `NSFetchedResultsController` in following aspects, since it doesn't provide following methods:

```
- [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles]
- [self.fetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index]
```

Another problem is that I want to sort like numbers come after letter as answered in this question [NSSortDescriptor - push # and numbers to the end of the list - iphone xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841798/nssortdescriptor-push-and-numbers-to-the-end-of-the-list-iphone-xcode)

I guess this is currently a limitation in RBQSortDescriptor since it doesn't provide following method:

```
+(RBQSortDescriptor *)sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:
```

What can I do to solve these using any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

`RBQFetchedResultsController` has two methods that should get you that info:

```c
// retrieve the title for a given section index
- (NSString *)titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

// retrieve the section index given a section name
- (NSUInteger)sectionIndexForSectionName:(NSString *)sectionName
```

Comment: yes, currently I using these methods & providing hard-coded array of a-z in [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles] method. How can I get array of section names so i can provide that array in [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles] method?

Comment: Ah, the API doesn't offer that but it wouldn't be too difficult to add. I will try to add that today with a PR.